# EF Core: Update database entity with infinite number of nested objects and relations

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework-core

In database, there are countless entities, for example: role, user, company - etc. Every of those entities are self referencing so they form trees and they have relationships one to another. So everything is interconnected with each other.

```
users: [{id: 1, children: [{id: 2}] companies: [{id:1, offers: [{id: 1, files: [{id: 1}]}]}]}]
```

Next, there is an API endpoint, where the user gets updated. New data comes as a JSON, with the same form as original database object. So basically, like this:

```
users: [{id: 1, children: [{id: 3}] companies: [{id:2, offers: [{id: 1, files: [{id: 1}]}]}]}]
```

In the example above I have updated user's children and companies. Data might have new items in arrays, might have items removed, modified - but its always the latest snapshot of a database entity and all entities already present.

My problem is I cannot figure out, how to update user entity without writing completely custom implementation for this endpoint. The idea behind the endpoint, is that it has to be able to handle data dynamically, without any sort of custom implementation.

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSystemUser(
            [Caller] SystemUser caller, [FromForm]int key, [FromForm]string values, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {}
```

values - contains JSON data.
I tried this:

```
 JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, user, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
            });
```

But it fails with Cannot track some objects. So I have try to manually track objects:

```
 foreach (var userProvider in user.providers)
            {
                _context.TryAttach(userProvider);
            }
```

This drops all of my provider objects, instead of updating them.
I tried to write custom deserialisation mechanism to automatically attach to deserialized objects:

```
public class ExtendedJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public ExtendedJsonConverter(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return ReadObject(reader, existingValue);
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return ReadList(reader, existingValue);
            default:
                return reader.Value;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    private object ReadValue(JsonReader reader, object existingValue, out JsonToken jsonToken)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
        {
            if (!reader.Read())
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException("Unexpected end.");
            }
        }
    
        switch (jsonToken = reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return this.ReadObject(reader, existingValue);
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return this.ReadList(reader, existingValue);
            default:
                // var value = reader.Value;
                // if (value == null)
                // {
                //     return null;
                // }
                //
                // var type = reader.ValueType;
                // if (type?.IsGenericType == true && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) 
                // {
                //     type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
                // }
                //
                // if (type == null)
                // {
                //     return null;
                // }
                //
                // if (type.IsEnum)
                // {
                //     value = Enum.ToObject(type, value);
                // }
                // var result = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
                
                return reader.Value;
        }
    }

    private object ReadList(JsonReader reader, object existingValue)
    {
        IList temp = null;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return temp;
                default:
                    var val = this.ReadValue(reader, existingValue, out var jsonToken);
                    if (val != null)
                    {
                        if (temp == null)
                        {
                            var t = val.GetType();
                            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
                            if ((temp = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType)) == null)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                                    $"Unable to create list of type: {listType}");
                            }
                        }

                        /*
                         * We have to handle 3 object's states: new, existing tracked and existing untracked.
                         */
                        var found = ((IList)existingValue).FindFirst(val);
                        if (found == null)
                        {
                            var propertyInfos = 
                                val.GetType().GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower().Equals("id"));
                            if (propertyInfos != null && propertyInfos.GetValue(val) != null)
                            {
                                _dbContext.TryAttach(val);
                            }
                        }
                        temp.Add(found ?? val);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
        throw new OperationCanceledException("Unexpected end.");
    }

    private object ReadObject(JsonReader reader, object existingValue)
    {
        var container = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    var propertyName = reader.Value?.ToString();
                    if (!reader.Read())
                    {
                        throw new OperationCanceledException("Unexpected end.");
                    }
                    container[propertyName 
                              ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Property name is empty!")] = 
                        this.ReadValue(reader, existingValue, out var jt);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    var existingValueType = existingValue.GetType();
                    if (existingValueType.IsGenericType)
                    {
                        existingValueType = existingValueType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
                    }

                    return ToObject(container, existingValueType);
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    return this.ReadList(reader, existingValue);
            }
        }
        throw new OperationCanceledException("Unexpected end.");
    }
    
    public object ToObject(IDictionary<string, object> source, [NotNull] Type type)
    {
        var someObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(item.Key);
            if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                var value = item.Value;
                var t = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) 
                {
                    t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
                }
                if (t == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                if (t.IsEnum)
                {
                    value = Enum.ToObject(t, item.Value);
                }
                
                var result =
                    value != null ? Convert.ChangeType(value, t) : value;
                propertyInfo.SetValue(someObject, result, null);
            }
        }

        return someObject;
    }
}
```

This fails as well.
Whole endpoint looks like this:

```
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("UpdateSystemUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSystemUser(
            [Caller] SystemUser caller, [FromForm]int key, [FromForm]string values, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Fetch providers, if assigned
            
            
            var user = 
                await _userManager.Users
                    .Include(x => x.roles)
                    .Include(x => x.companies)
                    .Include(x => x.providers)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == key, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, user, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
            });


            await _authFacade.Update(caller, user, cancellationToken);
            
            var (systemUser, token) = 
                await _authFacade.GenerateActivationDataAsync(user);

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(systemUser, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = 
                    new ExtendedContractResolver(
                        ignoredProperties: new Dictionary<Type, string[]>
                        {
                            [typeof(SystemRole)] = new []{nameof(SystemRole.users)},
                            [typeof(Company)] = new []{nameof(Company.users), nameof(Company.parent)},
                            [typeof(Provider)] = new []{nameof(Provider.users)}
                        })
            });

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Auth facade update method:

```
    public async Task<SystemUser> Update(SystemUser caller, SystemUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            throw new Exception(result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description).Aggregate((i, j) => i + ", " + j));
        }
        return user;
    }
```

I do believe, there should be some sort of unified solution for this and I don't need to write any custom acrobatics to deal with it. Ofc I can walk those objects one by one, analyze, invent some custom logic - but isn't there some 1 liner that deals with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: There's no EF or database code in the question.  EF deals with entities, not JSON and has no problem working with nested graphs as long as the relations are OK. This can be as simple as having a Parent/Child relation, eg `Employee.Manager`. JSON is almost *never* handled directly in an web app either, it's deserialized into objects by ASP.NET Core

Comment: I added endpoint code

Comment: That doesn't explain why you try to mix JSON and EF instead of working with entities like `SystemUser`. JSON is just a text format, **nothing** more. A JObject is just a way to represent that text, not an application entity and definitely not something that can be mapped to tables. A JsonConverter's only job is to map JSON text to an actual type if the standard mapping isn't appropriate. It's definitely not meant to be your application's database layer. It will be called by ASP.NET Core *before* your action is actually called, to map the request JSON into action parameters

Comment: All my hundreds of endpoints work that way. Data comes in JSON format, mapped to actual entity and entity is updated. I don't use DTO, I use JSON to pass data from FE to BE.

Comment: normal behaviour is that it just works. So your goal is to streamline your model as much as possible, make sure the stuff is serialized correct, then just attach it and savechanges and that should generate everying